# Oracle HASH_JOIN_RIGHT_SEMI performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, database-performance

Here is my query,

```
SELECT si.* FROM 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEMS si
 WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM id_map WHERE code = 'A' )
   AND LAST_UPDATED BETWEEN TO_DATE('20150102','YYYYMMDD') - 1 AND TO_DATE('20150103','YYYYMMDD')
```

SHIPMENT_ITEMS is a very large table (10.1TB) , id_map is a very small table (12 rows and 3 columns). This query goes through HASH_JOIN_RIGHT_SEMI and takes a very long time.SHIPMENT_ITEMS is partitioned on ID column.

If I remove subquery with hard code values , it performs lot better

```
 SELECT si.* FROM 
    FROM SHIPMENT_ITEMS si
     WHERE ID IN (1,2,3 )
       AND LAST_UPDATED BETWEEN TO_DATE('20150102','YYYYMMDD') - 1 AND TO_DATE('20150103','YYYYMMDD')
```

I cannot remove the subquery as it leads to hard coding.

Given that id_map is a very small table , I expect both queries to perform very similar. Why is the first one taking much longer.

I'm actually trying to understand why this performs so bad.

**I expect dynamic partition pruning to happen here and I'm not able to come out with a reason on why its not happening**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_avail.htm#BABHDCJG

Comment: IN is very low on performance, did you try joining the tables? or using exists?

Comment: It would help to add the explain plans for both queries to see what the difference is between them.  Run `explain plan for select ...;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and then post the *entire* output here.  Also, are these the real queries being run?  It seems like they would return millions of rows, which usually doesn't make sense.  Are you comparing the time to return *all* the rows or just the first N rows from some IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Try hint *no_unnest*.

```
SELECT si.* FROM 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEMS si
 WHERE ID IN ( SELECT /*+ NO_UNNEST */ ID FROM id_map WHERE code = 'A' )
   AND LAST_UPDATED BETWEEN TO_DATE('20150102','YYYYMMDD') - 1 AND TO_DATE('20150103','YYYYMMDD')
```

CBO will not try to join subquery and use it like filter

Comment: You can also explain to the OP and other people that will read this what exactly this hint does.

Comment: hint means that CBO will not try to join subquery and use it like filter

Comment: Not to me , to the people who reads it.. Hint: edit your question and write it there

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using 'in' operator, use exists and check the query performance

```
SELECT si.* FROM 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEMS si
 WHERE Exists ( SELECT 1 FROM id_map map WHERE map.code = 'A' and map.ID = so.ID)
   AND LAST_UPDATED BETWEEN TO_DATE('20150102','YYYYMMDD') - 1 AND TO_DATE('20150103','YYYYMMDD')
```